# Ubuntu 16.04 boot taking more then 5 mins

Tags: boot, 16.04

I'm using a hp laptop with 4 gb ram and 2.2 GHz amd processor and Ununtu 16.04 installed in it.
Before I was using windows 7. I formatted the whole harddisk and installed Ubuntu.

It boots some times very slowly. It take 5-10 mins(not all the time some time it boots very fast less then a min).
I don't have much applications installed in int and I checked startup apps there is also nothing.

here is the System log of boot:

```
May  2 00:24:11 purush systemd-logind[713]: System is powering down.
May  2 00:24:53 purush systemd-logind[646]: New seat seat0.
May  2 00:24:53 purush systemd-logind[646]: Watching system buttons on         /dev/input/event2 (Power Button)
May  2 00:24:53 purush systemd-logind[646]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (Video Bus)
May  2 00:24:53 purush systemd-logind[646]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
May  2 00:24:53 purush systemd-logind[646]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Lid Switch)
May  2 00:24:53 purush systemd-logind[646]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event11 (HP WMI hotkeys)
May  2 00:24:57 purush lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May  2 00:24:57 purush lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
May  2 00:24:57 purush lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May  2 00:24:57 purush lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
May  2 00:24:57 purush lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
May  2 00:24:57 purush systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
May  2 00:24:57 purush systemd-logind[646]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
May  2 00:24:59 purush lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May  2 00:24:59 purush lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
May  2 00:24:59 purush lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May  2 00:24:59 purush lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
May  2 00:24:59 purush lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "purush"
May  2 00:28:57 purush pkexec[1117]: lightdm: The value for the SHELL variable was not found the /etc/shells file [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/var/lib/lightdm] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/usd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 76]
May  2 00:31:25 purush pkexec[1122]: lightdm: The value for the SHELL variable was not found the /etc/shells file [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/var/lib/lightdm] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/usd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 255]
May  2 00:31:33 purush lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session):     session closed for user lightdm
May  2 00:31:33 purush lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session     opened for user purush by (uid=0)
May  2 00:31:33 purush systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session):     session opened for user purush by (uid=0)
May  2 00:31:33 purush systemd-logind[646]: New session c2 of user purush.
May  2 00:31:38 purush gnome-keyring-daemon[1160]: The SSH agent was     already initialized
May  2 00:31:38 purush gnome-keyring-daemon[1160]: The PKCS#11     component was already initialized
May  2 00:31:38 purush gnome-keyring-daemon[1160]: The Secret Service was already initialized
May  2 00:31:38 purush polkitd(authority=local): Registered     Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.110     [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object     path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_IN)
May  2 00:31:53 purush systemd-logind[646]: Removed session c1.
```

Comment: Could you give `systemd-analyze blame` information?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, and solved mine just now. Apparently in the /etc/fstab there was a reference for a swap partition that is nonexistent on my secondary hard drive because I've formatted it earlier today. And that's when it started to take 2-3 min to boot. It was booting in 10 seconds before that.
As mentioned on here [archbang forum](http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?pid=25745#p25745)

I commented out that part on fstab file `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` and it was fixed.